# Query to find root table using child table to any level, recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am trying to find the referenced tables of a table from bottom to top using the following recursive CTE query

```
With CTE_ALL AS
(
    SELECT
       1 as TopLevel, c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, cu.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable,
           cu.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencingColumn,ku.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable,
           ku.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
           ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku
           ON ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
     where cu.TABLE_NAME = 'my table name'
Union All
    SELECT
           2 as BelowLevels, c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, cu.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable,
           cu.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencingColumn,ku.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable,
           ku.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
           ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku
           ON ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
     INNER JOIN CTE_ALL CTE on CTE.ReferencedColumn = ku.COLUMN_NAME
           and CTE.ReferencedTable = ku.TABLE_NAME
)
select *
  from CTE_ALL
 where CTE_ALL.ReferencingTable = 'my table name'
```

It errors out giving the following message

```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before
statement completion.
```

which obviously means that my query is deviously planned to exhaust all SQL resources.
Due diligence from Microsoft prevents this.
I am wondering if I can do this without a while loop using a single query and no temporary tables.

I know my root table name and my root column id and I also know my leaf node table name though I cannot say what might be the leaf node column name

I have to find this because I am designing a query at runtime and executing it. This query needs the inner joins in between with the ON clause to be constructed at runtime. Not sure whether I am making sense that I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after days of trying and researching, I found a way to help myself and also after knowing recursive CTE's better.

For all of those who might find it useful

This is the query which I could finalize on

```
DECLARE @REFERENCED_COLUMN VARCHAR(50) = 'MyColumn'
DECLARE @REFERENCING_TABLE VARCHAR(50) = 'MyTable'

    ;WITH
        CTE_Relationship (ReferencingTable, ReferencingColumn, ReferencedTable, ReferencedColumn) AS
        (
            SELECT
                CU.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable, CU.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencingColumn,
                KU.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable, KU.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KU ON KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
        ),
        CTE_Recursive_Relationship (ReferencingTable, ReferencingColumn, ReferencedTable, ReferencedColumn, Pass) AS
        (
            SELECT
                R.ReferencingTable, R.ReferencingColumn, R.ReferencedTable, R.ReferencedColumn, 1 AS Pass
            FROM
                CTE_Relationship R
            WHERE
                R.ReferencingTable = @REFERENCING_TABLE

        UNION ALL

            SELECT
                R.ReferencingTable, R.ReferencingColumn, R.ReferencedTable, R.ReferencedColumn, RR.Pass + 1
            FROM
                CTE_Relationship R
                INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive_Relationship RR ON R.ReferencingTable = RR.ReferencedTable
                    AND R.ReferencedColumn = @REFERENCED_COLUMN
        )
        SELECT
            DISTINCT RR.*
        FROM
            CTE_Recursive_Relationship RR
        ORDER BY RR.Pass
```